# Stop moving element moving while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a movable element along the page, but little bit before my contact section I want to stop it. So I cant find right CSS property, or maby I can't do it with CSS? 
So my code is: 
JS:

```
var kontaktOffset = $('.kontakt').offset().top + 100;

if (wScroll > kontaktOffset - ($(window).height() / 0.9)) {

    var eboy = $('#eboy').addClass('stop');
}
else {

    var eboy = $('#eboy').removeClass('stop');
}
```

CSS:

```
.stop {
    position: fixed;


}
```

For now my element -> **#eboy** disappears. 
So does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Pixel http://dev.epartner.rs/ here is link to the website, so problem is when **#eboy** come to the bottom it disappears.
Sry it is not optimize for all screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll function is changing the margin-top of #eboy. #eboy has a position absolute, so changing it to fixed at a certain scrollTop will not solve what you want.

What I would do is in the scroll function apply an if statement and there you can introduce your margin-top #eboy change so it only applies if (wScroll < kontaktOffset - ($(window).height() / 0.9)).